# Using imported data Java

Tags: java, file, arraylist, io

I'm just learning to use File I/O and struggling to figure out how to use the data. For example, I have a .txt file that is setup with a name and list of scores that apply to that name, each list ending with a -1. I have successfully imported the file and was able to print it on the console but I need to add this information to an ArrayList so I can sort it, find the high and low, and the average and median. When I attempt to enter the data into an ArrayList I get a Exception I don't know how to handle. Here is the code I have so far, any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
File file = new File("Project11input.txt");
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
ArrayList<Integer> TerryCrews = readNextSeries(inFile);
int median = getMedian(TerryCrews);
System.out.println("The median is " + median);
int average = getAverage(TerryCrews);
System.out.println("The average is " + average);
}

private static ArrayList<Integer> readNextSeries(Scanner inScanner) {
    ArrayList<Integer> Input = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int thesex = 0;
    while(thesex >= 0){
        thesex = inScanner.nextInt();
        Input.add(thesex);
    }
    System.out.println("End of input");
return Input;}

private static int getMedian(ArrayList<Integer> inList) {
    int last = 0;
    int power = (inList.size()/2) - 1;
    int pow=0;
    int ful = power+1;
    int wap =0;
    int onetwo = inList.size()%2;
    if(onetwo == 1){
        last = inList.get(ful);}
    else{
        pow = inList.get(power);
        wap = inList.get(ful);
        last = (pow + wap);
                last=last/2;
    }

    return last;    }
```

to clarify, I basically need the numbers in the File "file" to be in an ArrayList so they can be used.

Comment: Exception trace please

Comment: Tbh idk what that means